# fstring not reading from .txt file

Tags: c++, fstream, iostream

I am trying to write a program that will read a .txt file that is called when the program is run from terminal.

the command used will be;
`$ ./myexecutable input.txt`

My program and the input.txt are in the same directory. My code so far is as follows

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc , char* argv[]){
    string temp = "here";
    string filename = argv[1];
    ifstream myFile (filename);
    myFile.open(filename);
    if (myFile.is_open()){
        while (getline (myFile, temp)){
            cout << temp << endl;   
            myFile.close();
        }
    } else {
        cout <<< "You have Entered Wrong File Name" << endl;
    }

    cout << "do with the simple program" << endl;
    return 1;
};
```

but the output I get is just

`file opened, do with the simple program`

I am not really familiar with fstream so don't know where I may have gone wrong. I followed their tutorial found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/).
but clearly I've done something wrong.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Get `myFile.close();` out of the loop. You don't want to close the file after reading 1 line. You can just delete that line completely. The stream will close the file when it goes out of scope. As a result I voted to close as a typo.

Comment: I expect the first line of your file is `file opened,` if this is indeed the code you are using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the corrected code!!
You were opening `myFile` twice!!
First time in this statement `ifstream myFile (filename);`
Second time in this statement-`myFile.open(filename);`

```
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main(int argc , char* argv[]){
        string temp = "here";
        string filename = argv[1];
        ifstream myFile (filename);
        if (myFile.is_open()){
            while (getline (myFile, temp)){
                cout << temp << endl;
                myFile.close();
            }
        } else {
            cout << "You have Entered Wrong File Name" << endl;
        }
    
        cout << "do with the simple program" << endl;
        return 1;
    };
```

Comment: You still have the `myFile.close();`  bug I mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: Look at the other close